# How to set role for user in login method - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is project that uses `Web Service` for get or set data on database.

For login method i send username and password, if  it is correct `web service` returns role and id.

How can i set this role for this user?

I must check this role for each action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow each user by their roles you can use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class SomeController : Controller
```

or if you want to, you can just allow each method individually:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

I didn't quite get what you were asking, but i read the title again and if u want to assign a role to a user use this:

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Guest");
```

Being `"Guest"` the role.
I think you should use this on the register method instead of the login.
Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but web service returned `ID,RL(means Role)` where and how I must set `RL` to Role of user?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are asking... You want to assign a role to a user? I added some code for that. @Farzaneh

Answer (score 0):

Use Role based Authorization filter some thing like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
}

Comment: yes, but web service returned `ID,RL(means Role)` where and how I must set `RL` to Role of user?